# JPA repository save() method replicating the same entity twice into mySQL DB while executing @Scheduled task in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, scheduled-tasks

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * ?") // Runs daily at 1 AM
public void applyDiscountDaily() {
    log.info("++++++++++at entry point of applyDiscountDaily+++++++++++++");
    // fetch list of pharmacy whose discount frequency is daily
    List<PharmacyDAO> pharmacyDAOs = pharmacyRepository.findPharmacyByDailyDiscount();
    if (pharmacyDAOs.size() > 0) {
        for (PharmacyDAO pharmacyDAO : pharmacyDAOs) {
            log.info("++++++++++into for loop+++++++++++++");
            PaymentDAO paymentDAO = new PaymentDAO();
            // get current month days
            int days = YearMonth.of(LocalDate.now().getYear(), LocalDate.now().getMonth())
                    .lengthOfMonth();
            // apply discount % on exposure
            Double roundedDebitedAmount = CommonUtil
                    .roundWithTwoDecimalDigits((pharmacyDAO.getDiscountPercentage() / days
                            * (pharmacyDAO.getCreditLimit()
                                    - pharmacyDAO.getAvailabilityBalance()))
                            / 100);
            paymentDAO.setStatementType("Discount Fee");
            paymentDAO.setDebitedAmount(roundedDebitedAmount);

            // check total monthly discount is greater than monthly
            if (today == totalDaysInMonth) {
                Month desiredMonth = Month.of(currentYearMonth.getMonthValue());
                LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(currentYearMonth.getYear(), desiredMonth, 1);
                int lastDayOfMonth = desiredMonth.length(startDate.isLeapYear());
                LocalDate endDate = LocalDate
                        .of(currentYearMonth.getYear(), desiredMonth, lastDayOfMonth)
                        .atStartOfDay()
                        .toLocalDate();
                Double totalMonthlyDiscount = transactionPaymentRepository
                        .getMonthlyDiscountAmountTotal(
                                pharmacyDAO.getId(),
                                startDate, endDate);
                paymentDAO.setDebitedAmount(roundedDebitedAmount);
                if ((totalMonthlyDiscount + roundedDebitedAmount) < pharmacyDAO
                        .getMinimumFee()) {
                    paymentDAO.setDebitedAmount(
                            CommonUtil.roundWithTwoDecimalDigits(
                                    totalMonthlyDiscount
                                            + roundedDebitedAmount));
                }
            }

            // If the discount fee is less than the minimum fee, the minimum fee must be
            // charged to the pharmacy and NOT the discount fee
            // if (roundedDebitedAmount < pharmacyDAO.getMinimumFee()) {
            // roundedDebitedAmount = pharmacyDAO.getMinimumFee(); //comment on 26 sep 10:25
            // paymentDAO.setStatementType("Minimum Fee");
            // paymentDAO.setDebitedAmount(roundedDebitedAmount);
            // }
            Double newAvailableBalance = CommonUtil
                    .roundWithTwoDecimalDigits(pharmacyDAO.getAvailabilityBalance()
                            - paymentDAO.getDebitedAmount());
            paymentDAO.setExposure(
                    CommonUtil.roundWithTwoDecimalDigits(
                            Math.abs(pharmacyDAO.getCreditLimit()
                                    - newAvailableBalance)));
            paymentDAO.setPharmacyDAO(pharmacyDAO);

            AuditLogsDAO auditLogsDAO = new AuditLogsDAO();
            auditLogsDAO.setPharmacyName(pharmacyDAO.getPharmacyName());
            auditLogsDAO.setUserEmail(adminEmail);
            auditLogsDAO.setAdminId(1l);
            auditLogsDAO.setUserName("Admin");
            auditLogsDAO.setRole(1l);
            auditLogsDAO.setRequestType(paymentDAO.getStatementType());
            auditLogsDAO.setAction("Admin");
            SchedularDiscountDTO discountDTO = SchedularDiscountDTO.builder()
                    .pharmacyId(pharmacyDAO.getId())
                    .availableBalance(newAvailableBalance)
                    .debitedAmount(paymentDAO.getDebitedAmount())
                    .discountPercentage(pharmacyDAO.getDiscountPercentage())
                    .discountFrequency(pharmacyDAO.getDiscountFrequency())
                    .statementType(paymentDAO.getStatementType())
                    .createdDate(LocalDateTime.now())
                    .build();
            try {
                auditLogsDAO.setData(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(discountDTO));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new JSONParseException("Unable to process JSON");
            }
            pharmacyDAO.setAvailabilityBalance(newAvailableBalance);
            log.info(" Current time : " + LocalDateTime.now()
                    + "...Discount fee debited daily for pharmacy : "
                    + pharmacyDAO.getEmailId()
                    + ", debited amount ="
                    + paymentDAO.getDebitedAmount());
            log.info("+++++++++++before saved payment object.++++++++++++");
            transactionPaymentRepository.save(paymentDAO);
            log.info("+++++++++++Saved payment object.+++++++++++++");
            pharmacyRepository.save(pharmacyDAO);
            log.info("+++++++++++Saved pharmacy object.+++++++++++++");
            auditLogsRepository.save(auditLogsDAO);
            log.info("+++++++++++Saved audit log object.+++++++++++++");
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented save method in JPA repository and annotated it with @Transactional still it replicated the entity. The logs are getting printed one time only but the object to save method gets replicated into database as a new entry.

I kept the ID as generated type Identity in entity. The code works fine at local but when i deploy my war file on EC2 instance with rds mySQL DB, then the replication scenario occurs. The logs are getting printed one time only.